# Swift: Can't initialize MKPlaceMark with address

Tags: swift, mapkit

Cannot find an initializer for type 'MKPlacemark' that accepts an argument list of type '(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, addressDictionary: [NSString : String?])'

```
let addressDict =
                [kABPersonAddressStreetKey as NSString: self.store.address1,
                    kABPersonAddressCityKey as NSString: self.store.city,
                    kABPersonAddressStateKey as NSString: self.store.state,
                    kABPersonAddressZIPKey as NSString: self.store.zipCode]

                let place = MKPlacemark(coordinate: placemark.location.coordinate, addressDictionary: addressDict)
```

The initialize of MLPlacemark gives me that error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The *question mark* in the error message indicates that `self.store.address1` (and the other parameters) are *optionals* and need to be unwrapped ...

Comment: That was it. I will now understand that type of error forever. Thanks!